# How to Embed Excel file as oledb object inside ppt slide using openxml SDK

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to  Embed Excel file as oledb object inside ppt slide using openxml SDK nuget, what ever code I tried is not working properly.

I tried to create embeded object part and attach content. but when I open ppt it is showing error.